# Why does instance_eval succeed with a Proc but not with a Lambda?

Tags: ruby

I have the following class:

```
class User
  code1 = Proc.new { }
  code2 = lambda { }

  define_method :test do
    self.class.instance_eval &code1
    self.class.instance_eval &code2
  end
end

User.new.test
```

Why does the second`instance_eval` fail with a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`instance_eval` is yielding `self` (`User`) to the lambda. Lambdas are particular about their parameters - in the same way methods are - and will raise an `ArgumentError` if there are too few/many.

```
class User
  code1 = Proc.new { |x| x == User } # true
  code2 = lambda { |x| x == User }   # true

  define_method :test do
    self.class.instance_eval &code1
    self.class.instance_eval &code2
  end
end
```

Relevant: [What's the difference between a proc and a lambda in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740083/382982)

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648157/instance-evals-block-arguments-documented-purpose

Comment: In my version lambda is not taking any argument. And I'm not passing any at the time of instance_eval. So why this issue of arguments number mismatch .

Comment: `instance_eval` is yielding self to the proc/lambda.

Comment: Yes got it. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval  in order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables.

Answer (score 13):

If you still want to use lambda, this code will work:

```
block = lambda { "Hello" } # or -> { "Hello" }
some_obj.instance_exec(&block)
```

`instance_exec` contrary to `instance_eval` will not supply `self` as an argument to the given block, so `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` won't be thrown.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648344/120992) for more info.