# Ruby lambda's proc's and 'instance_eval'

Tags: ruby

When I pass a lambda to `instance_eval` as the block, it seems to pass an extra argument:

```
lamb = -> { puts 'hi' }
proc = Proc.new { puts 'hi' }
instance_eval(&lamb)
# >> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
#    from (irb):5:in `block in irb_binding'
#    from (irb):7:in `instance_eval'
instance_eval(&proc)
# => hi
instance_exec(&lamb)
# => hi
```

Why is this the case? Note that this question is NOT about why lambda throws an error. That is well understood. The question is about WHY `instance_eval` sends `self` of the receiver as a parameter. It is not needed, and confusing. And AFAIK not documented.

[This](https://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/the-difference-between-instanceeval-and-instanceexec) helps, but doesn't explain WHY ruby would do it this way. The whole point of `instance_eval` is to set `self` to the receiver; why confuse things by also passing `self` to the proc?

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648157/instance-evals-block-arguments-documented-purpose), though not really answered in my opinion

Comment: It is not just for `instance_eval`. Other methods like `tap` (and `Thread.new`) work in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs

> For procs created using lambda or ->() an error is generated if the
>   wrong number of parameters are passed to a Proc with multiple
>   parameters. For procs created using Proc.new or Kernel.proc, extra
>   parameters are silently discarded.

In your case both `lamb` and `proc` called with one parameter

[From the docs of instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)

> When instance_eval is given a block, obj is also passed in as the
>   block's only argument

`instance_eval` is method of `BasicObject` class and can be called within instance. So given block will have access for private methods for example.

```
class Test
  def call
    secret_number + 100
  end
  private
  def secret_number
    42
  end
end

test = Test.new
show_secret = -> (obj) { puts secret_number }

test.instance_eval(&show_secret) # print 42
```

Without instance `self` of current context will be passed as an argument. I think `instance_eval` was designed more for calling it within objects.

[From the docs of instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)

> In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the
>   code is executing, giving the code access to obj's instance variables
>   and private methods.

Comment: yes I understand that... The question is why is there this extra parameter being passed from instance_eval... I can find it documented nowhere.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn, it is in documentation of [instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)

Comment: Thanks... Answer accepted.   Still is most curious why ruby would do this.  Seeing as I have access to self inside the block, why add this complication.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn, because `instance_eval` was intended for use within instances, check updated answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% satisfied but its seems this is a comprimise so that things like `each(&:puts)` will work.  Its just unfortunate that instance_eval does not ask if the proc is a lambda (and if it is DONT add the extra param)

Comment: just posted a detailed answer here on my theory of why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648157/instance-evals-block-arguments-documented-purpose/52643962#52643962